# Better way to Remote Connection?

Tags: c#

I would like to learn Remote connection with my client. 
Which is the best way for remote connection?
What should I learn?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Communication Foundation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx

WCF has unified high level programming model. It contains different transport layers (optimized for inter-process communication on the same computer, LAN or Internet). Changing the transport layer doesn't affect the program code. WCF is supposed to replace old communication technologies like .NET Remoting.